# With "Tableau": Issue with a filter which works well between 3 Dashboards, but no longer works when switching to the Storyboard

Tags: filter, storyboard, settings, dashboard, tableau-desktop

With **Tableau Desktop 2023.2.2**, I created a filter on a World Map on the **first** page of my **Dashboard**, which allows me to sort out countries that have an too low level of political stability and exclude them from certain views of my three Dashboards. The filter is used on the following two Dashboards and in Dashboard mode, it works well.
When I switch to **Storyboard** mode, this filter no longer works on pages 2 and 3, but on page 1 exclusively.
[Fig.1) Page 1 (Dashboard sort out countries that have an too low level of political stability)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6i8LL.png) 
[Fig.2) Page 2 (Dashboard - Coutnries have been excluded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yO45H.png)
[Fig.3) Page 2 (Storyboard - the filter don't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bkIB.png)

I have selected all spreadsheet where the filter have to be active, on 3 Dashboard.
But it work only in mode Dashboard not in mode Storyboard.
[Fig.4) Filter setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKCS5.png)

I need to know if there are other settings and how to configure my filter to also work on page 2 and 3 of my Storyboard or if it's just a Tableau bug?